# Is there anyway to use configure-server with servlet context path when register on service discovery?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I have a `service-discovery` which register all the services. I have `configure-server` which maintain all the configuration. configure-server already register in `service-discovery`. I know by default configure-server will register with id: configserver. I know how to change the id. But when I tried to use `servlet.context.path= /config`  all the configure-client can not pull from `configure-sever` through `service-discovery` look like can not use /config in `configure-server`.

configure-server:

```
server:
  port: 0
  servlet:
    context-path: /config
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/PheaSoy/spring-completed-microservice
          search-paths: config/{application}
      discovery:
        enabled: true
```

configure-client

```
spring:
  application:
    name: song-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://configserver/config
      discovery:
        enabled: true
```

Even I added context path /path configure-client always fetched without context path.

```
ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://192.168.1.34:57945/
```

Is there any way to configure configure-client with available configure-server context path through service-discovery?

Answer (score 1):

> The discovery client implementations all support some kind of metadata map (for example, we have eureka.instance.metadataMap for Eureka). Some additional properties of the Config Server may need to be configured in its service registration metadata so that clients can connect correctly. If the Config Server is secured with HTTP Basic, you can configure the credentials as user and password. Also, if the Config Server has a context path, you can set configPath. For example, the following YAML file is for a Config Server that is a Eureka client:

bootstrap.yml.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    ...
    metadataMap:     
      configPath: /config
```

**Reference**:

[Spring Cloud Config with Eureka - contextPath](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1242)

[Discovery with bootstrap](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#discovery-first-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define your context path for your configuration server as you have done.

But doing so, you also need to take into account the alignments you need to do.

1. Eureka. By default will call your management API. For example, http://BASE_URI/actuator/health. But since you are adding a context path "config", it means it should be now: http://BASE_URI/config/actuator/health. You can correct following the suggestion above on `eureka.instance...metadataMap.configPath: /config`
2. Configuration Clients. In your application (client to the config server), you can add the context path in `spring.cloud.config.uri`. For example, if it was "http://BASE_URI", then it should be updated as "http://BASE_URI/config" now since you added a context path.

Please try and see if it helps.